# How to use properties in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, object, properties, retain

When should I use the `nonatomic`, `retain`, `readonly` and `readwrite` properties in Objective-C?

For example:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSObject *myObject;
```

If I use `nonatomic` and `retain`, does this mean that the object will be retained?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Atomic vs nonatomic properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/atomic-vs-nonatomic-properties)

Comment: @David I don't think so. This question is more about properties in general. Not just `nonatomic` and `atomic`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, I wanted to promote the comment from David Gelhar to a full answer. The modifiers `atomic` and `nonatomic` have nothing to do with thread safety. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/atomic-vs-nonatomic-properties) for more detail in that space.

The other items you listed can be addressed relatively simply. I'll hit them briefly and point you toward the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1) on property modifiers if you want more.

`atomic` vs `nonatomic` primarily ensures that complete values are returned from synthesized getters and that complete values are written by synthesized setters.

`readwrite` vs `readonly` determines whether a synthesized property has a synthesized accessor or not (`readwrite` has a setter and is the default, `readonly` does not).

`assign` vs `retain` vs `copy` determines how the synthesized accessors interact with the Objective-C memory management scheme. `assign` is the default and simply performs a variable assignment. `retain` specifies the new value should be sent `-retain` on assignment and the old value sent `-release`. `copy` specifies the new value should be sent `-copy` on assignment and the old value sent `-release`.

Comment: Also, care needs to be taken to use the setters and getters of the ivar, and not change the ivar directly, which circumvents the setters and getters. That is, use self.myValue = newValue, not myValue = newValue.

Comment: Absolutely, regarding the use of `self.myValue = newValue` vs `myValue=newValue`. If you are going to use properties, you need to make sure you use dot syntax or send the messages to self. Accessing the ivar directly would undermine quite a bit.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `nonatomic`, reading and writing the property will not be threadsafe. At this point I don't think it is something you need to worry about, but nonatomic access can be faster than atomic access which is why it is used here.

If you use `retain`, writing to the property will cause the outgoing value to be released and the incoming value retained, maintaining proper reference-count based ownership of the value.

Answer (score 1):

**nontomic** Basically, if you say nonatomic, and you generate the accessors using @synthesize, then if multiple threads try to change/read the property at once, badness can happen. You can get partially-written values or over-released/retained objects, which can easily lead to crashes. (This is potentially a lot faster than an atomic accessor, though.)

**atomic** is the default behavior. nonatomic is thread safe.
**readonly** Externally the property will be readonly.

**readwrite**  property will have both the accessor, and the setter.

**assign (default)** — Specifies that the setter uses simple assignment.
**retain** — Specifies that retain should be invoked on the object upon assignment.  This attribute is valid only for Objective-C object types. (You cannot specify retain for Core Foundation objects)

**copy** — Specifies that a copy of the object should be used for assignment. The previous value is sent a release message. The copy is made by invoking the copy method. This attribute is valid only for object types, which must implement the NSCopying protocol.

Comment: atomic != "thread safe".  It just means, well, atomic.   Any multi-threaded algorithms that share common data need synchronization to avoid race conditions, even with atomic.

Comment: Although, if you don't really care about exact ordering, if you have one writer and multiple readers in different threads, "atomic" is good enough, so in that sense it could be considered "thread safe"

Comment: @Bogatyr: Yea..! we cannot say it is not thread safe, it doest "gurantee" thread safety, where we are having multiple setters in multiple threads. Thank you :)